# SQL Server: compare two values only if none of them is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

The thing I'm trying to do is compare two columns but only if none of the is null.

In more detail, I want to get all the `product_ids` that have a `product_id,color_id` pair in both `stock` and `price` tables or a `null` `color_id` in any of them.

I came up with this which seems to do the work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    stock.product_id product_id
FROM  
    stock, price
WHERE
    stock.product_id = price.product_id 
    AND
    (stock.color_id = price.color_id 
     OR price.color_id IS NULL OR stock.color_id IS NULL)
```

But I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thank you.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Well, somehow I got curious at last. So here are my two questions: 1. What does color null mean in the stock table? 2. What does color null mean in the price table?

Comment: NULL colour in the stock table means that the stock is independent of colour and likewise NULL price means the products price is independent of its colour.

Comment: Ah, I see. So for one product there can never be a record for red and for null at the same time in one table, because either we state a price per color or one common price, and either there is a storage shelf per color or one for the product.

Comment: One more question: What are the tables natural keys? Is there only one record per product and color in each table or can there be more?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There is only one record per product-colour combination, OR only one record with NULL colour_id, same applies to size as well.

Comment: Okay, so they are distinct already. I've deleted my answer telling you to make them distinct first, and added a new answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do this way.
I don't know about the performance of the query Coz I am new to performance of SQl.
But I think `Subquery` will be the good option for you.

Here is the query that might help you.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    stock.product_id Stock_ProductId,
    price.product_id Price_ProductId,
    isnull(stock.color_id,0) Stock_color_id,
    isnull(price.color_id,0) Price_color_id,
FROM  
    stock 
    ,price
) AS A
WHERE
    Stock_ProductId = Price_ProductId 
AND
    ( Stock_color_id = Price_color_id OR Price_color_id  = 0 OR Stock_color_id  = 0)
```

I hope that this answer might help you.

**Note : This query is not tested**

Answer (score 0):

Here is another point of view. You may have a product with ten colors, seven of them in stock, six of them having a price, four matches. It would suffice to find *one* match. So why match all? And then even have to use DISTINCT to get rid of multiple matches?

The following is essentially your select, only put in an EXISTS clause. The dbms may make use of this and use quick lookup loops. I guess it depends on how many products and how many colors are in the tables, whether this is faster or not.

```
select id
from product
where exists
(
  select * 
  from stock s
  join price p 
    on s.product_id = p.product_id 
    and (s.color_id = p.color_id or p.color_id is null or s.color_id is null)
  where s.product_id = product.id
);
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this will be faster but I'll test it.

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but should work:

```
where ... and coalesce(stock.color_id, price.color_id, 0) = coalesce(price.color_id, stock.color_id, 0)
```

Comment: *Very Bad* idea. Applying functions to arguments prevents the server from using any indexes, resulting on full table scans.

Comment: I didn't use `COALESCE` but I did use `ISNULL` and here was a significant negative impact on performance, so I think @PanagiotisKanavos is right.

Comment: Just check the execution plan of your query to see what the server actually does. You can even type both variants in a query window and compare the performance differences. You'll see that the original version does an index seek while any functions on arguments result in table scans

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried it and by surprise it seems to be as fast as my approach, if not faster. It didn't result in a table scan though, it did the same `index scans` as mine with the only difference that mine did an extra `merge join` that the execution plan estimated as 30% of the batch.

Comment: An index scan is used if an index contains all the required fields, but it still results in scanning all data in the index. An index seek on the other does a B-Tree search for only the index entries that match the criteria.

Comment: In defence of my answer: (1) it is not very bad idea, if it is used as additional join condition like it is in current case - speed depends heavily on data statistics however; if there are relatively few variations, then query plan should become similar to original one  (2) it is more readable, because it is shorter (3) it is less readable, because another developer may not easily understand logic behind it. I see that (2) and (3) are contradicting :)

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the statement and it shouldn't be modified.

Applying functions to arguments in `JOIN` or `WHERE` clauses prevents the query optimizer from using any underlying indexes, thus forcing a full table scan instead of a much cheaper index seek.

Moreover, the statement says *return values that either match on color including those that have no color*. In this case, `NULL` is used as a wildcard. Any modification with `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` would also modify the logic to *return only those that match or both have no color*. This would be equivalent to:

```
stock.color_id = price.color_id OR (price.color_id IS NULL AND stock.color_id IS NULL)
```

This statement could be simplified if `Color_Id` contained a special value for `No Color`, eg `-1`. In this case you could simply write

```
stock.color_id = price.color_id
```

This won't simplify the original statement though, as the logic requires that you check both table for the `No Color` value

Comment: It is not requested that *both* colors are null, but at least *one* of them.

Comment: Sorry, then I simply misunderstand what you are saying.

Comment: Also, color_id is a foreign key so it can't be any number ( like `-1` as you mentioned )

Comment: It can, if you add the relevant entry. This is a typical scenario in reporting/data warehouse schemas to handle irregular values, with a different entry for each irregular value like `Unknown`, `Not Applicable`, 'Not Specified` etc.